# Unauthorized Access Error with Dify API in Python Gradio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, gradio, gradio-chatinterface

I’m trying to use the Dify API in my Python code to retrieve responses. However, I’m encountering an issue with the authorization. Here’s the error message I’m getting:

```
2023-12-29 19:34:58.421 | DEBUG    | mywebgpt:make_completion:36 - Chat/Completions Nb Retries : 0
2023-12-29 19:35:01.169 | DEBUG    | mywebgpt:make_completion:48 - Status Code : 200
2023-12-29 19:35:01.169 | ERROR    | mywebgpt:make_completion:55 - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
2023-12-29 19:35:01.169 | DEBUG    | mywebgpt:make_completion:36 - Chat/Completions Nb Retries : 1
2023-12-29 19:35:03.485 | DEBUG    | mywebgpt:make_completion:48 - Status Code : 200
2023-12-29 19:35:03.485 | ERROR    | mywebgpt:make_completion:55 - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
2023-12-29 19:35:03.485 | DEBUG    | mywebgpt:make_completion:36 - Chat/Completions Nb Retries : 2
2023-12-29 19:35:05.569 | DEBUG    | mywebgpt:make_completion:48 - Status Code : 200
2023-12-29 19:35:05.569 | ERROR    | mywebgpt:make_completion:55 - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here’s the relevant part of my code:

```
import gradio as gr

import asyncio, httpx
import async_timeout

from loguru import logger
from typing import Optional, List
from pydantic import BaseModel

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


class Message(BaseModel):
    role: str
    content: str

async def make_completion(messages:List[Message], nb_retries:int=3, delay:int=30) -> Optional[str]:

    header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer app-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
    try:
        async with async_timeout.timeout(delay=delay):
            async with httpx.AsyncClient(headers=header) as aio_client:
                counter = 0
                keep_loop = True
                while keep_loop:
                    logger.debug(f"Chat/Completions Nb Retries : {counter}")
                    try:
                        resp = await aio_client.post(
                            url = "https://api.dify.ai/v1/chat-messages",  # Update the API endpoint
                            json = {
                                "inputs": {},
                                "query": messages[-1]["content"],  # Use the last message as the query
                                "response_mode": "streaming",
                                "conversation_id": "",
                                "user": "abc-123"
                            }
                        )
                        logger.debug(f"Status Code : {resp.status_code}")
                        if resp.status_code == 200:
                            return resp.json()["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]
                        else:
                            logger.warning(resp.content)
                            keep_loop = False
                    except Exception as e:
                        logger.error(e)
                        counter = counter + 1
                        keep_loop = counter < nb_retries
    except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:
        logger.error(f"Timeout {delay} seconds !")
    return None

async def predict(input, history):


    history.append({"role": "user", "content": input})
    response = await make_completion(history)
    history.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response})
    messages = [(history[i]["content"], history[i+1]["content"]) for i in range(0, len(history)-1, 2)]
    return messages, history


with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    logger.info("Starting Demo...")
    chatbot = gr.Chatbot(label="MyBrain")
    state = gr.State([])
    with gr.Row():
        txt = gr.Textbox(show_label=False, placeholder="Type your question and press enter").style(container=False)
    txt.submit(predict, [txt, state], [chatbot, state])

demo.launch(server_port=8080)
```

I’ve checked my API key and it seems to be correct. I’ve also tried regenerating the key but the issue persists. Any help would be greatly appreciated!